# Visual C#, how can I set SetItemChecked property using Control?

Tags: c#, forms, controls, checkedlistbox

I have a form which contains several `CheckedListBox` items, along with other controls. I'm trying to loop through each the controls and set its property values. Unfortunately, the `SetItemChecked` property is is not available in the `Control` class, so I can't figure out how to manipulate the `Checked` state of the control.

Here's what I have so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Controls.Count(); i++) {
  switch(Controls[i].GetType().ToString()) {
    case "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox":
    case "System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox":
      Controls[i].Text=i.ToString();
        break;
    case "System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox":
      Controls[i].SetItemChecked(0,true);
      // ^^ This line doesn't work, because SetItemChecked is not available
      break;
    default:
      Controls[i].Tag=i;
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Alford for your editing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast the Control into a CheckedListBox Like this:

```
(Controls[i] as CheckedListBox).SetItemChecked(0,true);
```

I'm not sure of this one, but it might work also:

```
CheckedListBox myCbList= (ChecekdListBox) Controls[i];
myCbList.SetItemChecked(0,true)
```